# force function parameter keyword in TypeScript(Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want make a function, let it can be called like

```
addPets('Dog', someEvent);
```

there has problem on first parameter, I need force keyword, maybe a enum or type, but I don't know how do force that?

example:

```
export enum PetType {
    Cat  = 'Cat',
    Dog  = 'Dog',
    Fish = 'Fish'
}

addPets('Dog', someEvent); // fine
addPets('Cat', someEvent); // fine
addPets('Cow', someEvent); // error, because PetType not have Cow
```

thank every help.

Comment: Please clarify, do you want a type checking?

Comment: In my opinion, that parameter maybe don't need type checking

Comment: After all, this parameter is a default parameter and it is a string. If I use a type, I do n’t know how to implement it.

Comment: There is a jQuery example, .on ('click', ...), where the string 'click' is a valid value, while .on ('cow', ...) is not, similar to this.

Comment: You can create interface with string type but enum is more suitable here

Answer (score 2):

You should declare the argument type in your function signature and invoke it using the `PetType` `enum`.

```
function addPets(petType: PetType, ...): void {
   ...
}

addPets(PetType.Cat, someEvent);
addPets(PetType.Dog, someEvent);
```